# How do we deal with people utilising SEs for interests other than that specified in the site definitions?

Tags: discussion

I'm active on Physics and since the last few months, we've seen an influx of questions stemming from commercial and legal interests. The questions mostly follow the site's guidelines, and they don't seem promotional in content. But certain characteristics of such questions make them seem of an interest not those of "active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy" as specified in the [site definition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour). The questions were later closed as off-topic due to the same.

The questions might have some educational value useful for the community, but making use of the sincere services of users who want to contribute to society, for something else is not fair.

I think these questions challenge the very definition of Physics and other sites. Therefore, should we change the site definition to indicate utilisation of the site for such interests are not encouraged ?

Comment: If this question is about site scope, maybe this would be better discussed within the community on [meta.physics.se]?

Comment: Can you link to such a question so we have an example of what you're addressing?

Comment: @200_success I believe this is relevant for other meta sites like Chemistry meta as well, thought it would be better to post on the mother meta.

Comment: @Mureinik Will try. The questions were closed, might be non-existent already.

Comment: If these question have been closed and deleted, it seems like the site's self-moderation effort is doing what it's supposed to, no? So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: What are those questions? Just ONE example, please.

Comment: @Mureinik The present guidelines on the site(s) do not deal with such questions at all. There is nothing explicit to discourage the questions in the first place. Even though the questions are closed for good, the reasons available in the close-votes' queue for closing are not related to the question itself.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain ?

Comment: @DeerHunter [Here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192610/thermal-contact-burn)'s one post for you, but it's closed and non-existent now.

Comment: @Gaurav - can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @DeerHunter I don't know how I can take a screenshot of a long deleted question, as I have not done so before the question was deleted.

Comment: @Gaurav - how can you expect us to take the question seriously if you fail to provide any evidence?

Comment: @Gaurav - please at least paraphrase what the question was about if you cannot quote verbatim.

Comment: @DeerHunter Is the real question at all that important for the discussion at hand ? What would actually change about the discussion if the question was shown ?

Comment: @DeerHunter "how can you expect us to take the question seriously if you fail to provide any evidence?" Evidence of what ?

Comment: @Gaurav - I downvoted it and flagged to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: @Gaurav examples, please. How am I supposed to know what "but making use of the sincere services of users who want to contribute to society, for something else" means?

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Please point out the insufficiencies in the description I have provided of those type of questions in my question. Also, what would actually change about the discussion if the question was shown ?

Comment: I don't know where to begin. You're discussing about *Questions with seemingly promotional content.* Now what is that supposed to be? Spam? Advertisement? Now it becomes even vaguer when you say they have some *educational value*. Post the question, or else we'll keep not getting what you mean.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Please re-read my question, I mention that the questions are *not* promotional in nature. And they *do* have educational value to the community, but the OP has an unappropriate purpose behind it. If you are competent enough to reproduce the non-existent questions here, it would be very welcome.

Comment: @DeerHunter I have edited the question. Is it now sufficiently clear to be un-downvoted ?

Comment: @Gaurav - are you kidding? Where are the examples?

Comment: I have downvoted and flagged the question for closure

Comment: @DeerHunter: here is a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/u2uvj.png

Comment: @KyleKanos - thanks. Can see no problem with closing. Don't understand why Gaurav brought it to MSE. It's unclear and "too localized" (oh, sorry, **blatantly off-topic** on Physics.SE).

Answer (score 8):

The usual tools available are

- Vote to close as off topic (if you can).
- Flag as off topic (if you can't v-t-c yourself).
- Voting.
- Commenting to educate the OP.

or a combination thereof.

In addition to the above, you should ask a question on [your site's meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/) and open a discussion with the local community about what should be done.

The outcome of that discussion then becomes part of your communities consensus on the validity or not of certain types of question. If the community decides that it does not want that type of question, the meta discussion can then be used as part of a custom close reason. It could also be used as the basis for a canonical Q&A to which questions of that type are closed against.

The key thing is though to have the discussion with the physics community and work from there.

An example:

Serverfault had [this discussion](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/625/should-licensing-questions-be-closed) about licensing. It spawned this [canonical Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue). Software Licensing questions are now routinely closed as [duplicates](https://serverfault.com/search?q=licensing%20closed:1&s=32bdb5b1-8269-4091-ae64-801e5f014207) of it.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I think at present, there are no formal guidelines for these type of situations in the site. Although such questions can be closed, the reasons available in the close-votes' queue for closing are not appropriate for the types of questions at hand. Therefore, I think we are limited here by the "usual tools" you mention. (contd.)

Comment: Since these situations challenge the very definition of the site, I think it is worth modifying/adding guidelines, adding a new reason for closing in the review queue, or modifying the site definition to make it clear such questions are not entertained.

Comment: Also, I feel this is relevant to other sites like Chemistry as well. So I think posting it on Physics meta would result in an isolated discussion, thus the reason for posting on the mother meta.

Comment: One size does not fit all. Each site has to make it's own decisions on stuff like this, Chemistry may welcome them and Physics not or vice versa, or both or neither. The only way to find out is to have the discussion locally.

Comment: But why is my question inappropriate to be posted on the mother meta ?

Comment: Communities are allowed to decide for themselves what is topical and within scope, this is not dictated by mSE. More importantly most people who regularly opine here on mSE will not have have sufficient knowledge of or engagement with the target communities to be able to provide a relevant opinion. This really is a discussion that needs to take place within the communities it is relevant to.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have [re-posted](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/how-do-we-deal-with-people-utilising-physics-for-interests-other-than-that-speci?noredirect=1#comment27049_6927) it on Physics meta.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to say for sure without the context of the questions themselves (and, I believe, a bit of knowledge in the topic).

*General* advice withstanding, communities should occasionally explore how their topics are being served elsewhere to make sure that they're still *relevant* for new interests within the topic, provided that those interests can thrive in a framework of low-noise objective Q&A. That's just checking in on the competition and seeing what they're up to.

Now that you have what sounds like at least a few good examples, it's time to start a discussion on the Physics meta site. If you bring it up too early, you're kinda stabbing at things that haven't yet become problems, so it sounds like the right time to start the discussion.

Regarding the 'which meta should I use' conundrum, use your *per site* meta for issues that are intrinsic to your site. A great test would be "Does someone probably need to know something about [topic] for this to make sense?" If the answer is yes, go to your local meta.

If it's primarily about Stack Exchange, our company, our policies, our software or something that potentially affects all of our sites, come here. Bug reports and feature requests? Take your pick, mostly - but if the feature would primarily serve [topic], then it's better to talk about it on the [topic] meta.

Comment: Thanks, as per your advice I have [re-posted](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/how-do-we-deal-with-people-utilising-physics-for-interests-other-than-that-speci?noredirect=1#comment27049_6927) it on Physics meta.